# can not set ValueMember to listBox in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

I can't set ValueMember to listBox

I have class Skill

```
class Skill
    {
        public string skillId { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }

        public Skill()
        {
        }

        public Skill(string skillId, string name)
        {
            this.skillId = skillId;
            this.name = name;
        }
    }
```

I add list Skill to List

```
            List<Skill> skills = new List<Skill>();
            skills.Add(new Skill("1", "Long"));
            skills.Add(new Skill("2", "Nhi"));

            foreach (var item in skills)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(item);
                listBox1.ValueMember = "skillId";
                listBox1.DisplayMember = "name";
            }
```

The DisplayMember is displayed to listBox, but ValueMember not set to listBox
When I click selected an item in ListBox, and click button, I'm print

```
Console.WriteLine("value id listbox1:" + listBox1.SelectedValue);
```

but it display nothing

```
value id listbox1:
```

Comment: Please read https://xyproblem.info/ and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: i'm edited my question, pls check again and help me!

Comment: ValueMember and DisplayMember were meant to be used with a DataSource, not `Items.Add(...)`

Comment: So get rid of your for-each, and replace it with `listBox1.DataSource = skills;`

Comment: thank you, I understand, is there any way to add DisplayMember with Item.Add(), becasue when user select item in listBox and click remove, it must remove from listbox, if I use DataSource, it throw exception "Items collection cannot be modified when the DataSource property is set"

Comment: You remove items from the DataSource, not from the ListBox.  Prefer a `BindingList<T>` to a `List<T>`

Comment: @ĐứcLong what you just said above in your comment, you should add to the question. Because while `listBox1.DataSource = skills;` is a legit answer, in your case may be not working. But your question does not contain this specifics. Not everyone is reading comments before answering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is - you need to use `DataSourse` property for this

```
listBox1.ValueMember = "skillId";
listBox1.DisplayMember = "name";
listBox1.DataSource = skills; // where skills  = List<Skill>
```

And make sure that `DataSourse` is set last. It has performance implications.

If you need to remove items, you can either use `BindingList<Skill>` or don't bind to a list but to an array generated from this list (LINQ) - `skills.ToArray()`. Then you can always remove item from the list in memory and then call `listBox1.DataSource = skills.ToArray()` again.